# Cannot play video with link video from Google Drive

Tags: javascript, html

I have a video tag like this, it's always play when I visited my page, but it's not playing for now

How can autoplay the video when I visit with the link's Google shared from my Google drive with my example `video` tag like this

```html
<video id="video" poster="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1znNGRm03rDypls31NUBpjvRscpFoJc0h" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" controls="controls" playsinline width="100%" height="686">
    <source src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QEJnvR6B9tVgKyQJVWE8sHDVU_MqYLxB" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 2):

To embed a video from Google Drive for autoplay, you'll need to get the shareable link that allows the video to play directly.

```html
<video id="video" poster="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1QEJnvR6B9tVgKyQJVWE8sHDVU_MqYLxB" autoplay loop muted controls playsinline width="100%" height="686">
    <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1QEJnvR6B9tVgKyQJVWE8sHDVU_MqYLxB" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play a video from Google Drive, use the iframe tag, (Google Drive Embed option). Below is an example for your video:

```
<iframe
       width="100%"
       height="100%"
       src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QEJnvR6B9tVgKyQJVWE8sHDVU_MqYLxB/preview"
</iframe>
```

Additionally, you can use parameters in the url to transfer properties from the video tag to the iframe, e.g. autoplay.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

your video address in not valid.
you can use this:

```html
your video address in not valid.
you can use this:

<video id="video" poster="https://rr1---sn-q0cedn7s.c.drive.google.com/videoplayback?expire=1703164967&ei=9xGEZYgHsemlvQ-qz7zADQ&ip=45.15.157.253&id=6d38da5fa154ffff&itag=22&source=webdrive&requiressl=yes&xpc=EghonaK1InoBAQ==&mh=9R&mm=32&mn=sn-q0cedn7s&ms=su&mv=u&mvi=1&pl=24&ttl=transient&susc=dr&driveid=1QEJnvR6B9tVgKyQJVWE8sHDVU_MqYLxB&app=explorer&eaua=WIug9EHVF8Q&mime=video/mp4&vprv=1&prv=1&dur=149.908&lmt=1703145559382114&mt=1703153381&subapp=DRIVE_WEB_FILE_VIEWER&txp=0006224&sparams=expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,requiressl,xpc,ttl,susc,driveid,app,eaua,mime,vprv,prv,dur,lmt&sig=AJfQdSswRAIgGG8tsMkPOJErfkoaxDkB7vtqHKOd0CInGH-5uE9mJ0QCIGdX1uqElt4OZ8GCAzm_n07KkGK5LhuCE2ppJzBco4Kf&lsparams=mh,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl&lsig=AAO5W4owRAIgTMxEAh1nk9eYVWHI4eBIbLfOf1pqtIhtPZrHdTyXL00CIA7ZPClNF6ecVK9sknBoRZPKrt4zI9UzXk1ePIKl-GD-&cpn=nm3ai-44wu5T6QN5&c=WEB_EMBEDDED_PLAYER&cver=1.20231217.00.00" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" controls="controls" playsinline width="100%" height="686">
    <source src="https://rr1---sn-q0cedn7s.c.drive.google.com/videoplayback?expire=1703164967&ei=9xGEZYgHsemlvQ-qz7zADQ&ip=45.15.157.253&id=6d38da5fa154ffff&itag=22&source=webdrive&requiressl=yes&xpc=EghonaK1InoBAQ==&mh=9R&mm=32&mn=sn-q0cedn7s&ms=su&mv=u&mvi=1&pl=24&ttl=transient&susc=dr&driveid=1QEJnvR6B9tVgKyQJVWE8sHDVU_MqYLxB&app=explorer&eaua=WIug9EHVF8Q&mime=video/mp4&vprv=1&prv=1&dur=149.908&lmt=1703145559382114&mt=1703153381&subapp=DRIVE_WEB_FILE_VIEWER&txp=0006224&sparams=expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,requiressl,xpc,ttl,susc,driveid,app,eaua,mime,vprv,prv,dur,lmt&sig=AJfQdSswRAIgGG8tsMkPOJErfkoaxDkB7vtqHKOd0CInGH-5uE9mJ0QCIGdX1uqElt4OZ8GCAzm_n07KkGK5LhuCE2ppJzBco4Kf&lsparams=mh,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl&lsig=AAO5W4owRAIgTMxEAh1nk9eYVWHI4eBIbLfOf1pqtIhtPZrHdTyXL00CIA7ZPClNF6ecVK9sknBoRZPKrt4zI9UzXk1ePIKl-GD-&cpn=nm3ai-44wu5T6QN5&c=WEB_EMBEDDED_PLAYER&cver=1.20231217.00.00" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```